# unable to get correct typed input value without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can get the input value correctly the first time the handler is called. but it gives me the default value in the html template afterwards and without reloading pages. what might be the prolbem? Thank you!

```
render: function () {
        this.$tpl = $(this.options.template);
        this.$tpl.attr('id', this.newrowSelector);
        this.newrowSelector = (this.newrowSelector.charAt(0) == '#') ? this.newrowSelector : '#' + this.newrowSelector;
        this.$tpl.find(".actions").append(this.options.cancelButton);
        this.$tpl.find(".actions").append(this.options.saveButton);
        $(this.options.selector).append(this.$tpl);
        this.$newrow = $(this.newrowSelector);
        this.$element.on('click.tablerow.save', this.options.saveTarget, $.proxy(this.save, this));

    },
save: function () {
        var formdata = this.getValues();
        formdata.zone_id = $.pdns.getZoneId();
        this.$element.triggerHandler('saved.tablerow.linline', 
        [formdata]);
    },
getValues: function () {
        var formdata = {};
        $(this.newrowSelector).find('input,select').each(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var key = $(this).attr('id');
            formdata[key] = value;
        });
        return formdata;
    }
```

the following is the template:

```
<tr><td class="name" title="sub domain name"><input id="name" type="text" value="subdomain name"></td><td class="dnstype"><select class="dns-options" id="dnstype"><option>A</option><option>AAAA</option><option>CNAME</option><option>MX</option><option>NS</option></select></td><td class="ttl" ><input id="ttl" type="text" value="600"></td><td class="content"><input id="content" type="text" value="10.10.10.10"></td><td class="actions"></td></tr>
```

Comment: add an event listner onchange or oninput on the the input field.

Comment: Thank you , but that seems to make no difference. it works if I keep the template row there instead of $(this).remove() and adding it again after clicking the Add button